# Force evaluation in function factories

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

I was reading Advanced R from Hadley and got into this example:

```
boot_permute <- function(df, var) {
  n <- nrow(df)
  force(var)

  function() {
    col <- df[[var]]
    col[sample(n, replace = TRUE)]
  }
}

boot_mtcars1 <- boot_permute(mtcars, "mpg")
head(boot_mtcars1())
#> [1] 16.4 22.8 22.8 22.8 16.4 19.2
head(boot_mtcars1())
#> [1] 17.8 18.7 30.4 30.4 16.4 21.0
```

Could anybody explain me why he uses `force` on `var` but didn't do the same for `df`? I know the intention is to force the evaluation of the variable, but can't get it why he only did it for `var`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `nrow(df)` would force the evaluation of `df`. Since `var` wouldn't be evaluated until the inner function was actually evaluated, `var` would remain an unevaluated promise within the closure till that inner function is actually executed.. Using `force(var)` forces evaluation of that promise. So if you use the value of the variable in some way already, an explicit `force()` is not required.

Comment: Thank you! Another question, if I replace `nrow` by any other function would it still be true for the `df` variable?

Comment: Well, no, not *any* other function. You have to guarantee that the function will evaluate the parameter. Functions that use non-standard evaluation probably won’t evaluate the variable. But most functions would probably work. If you want to be safe, there would be no harm in using `force()`